# gnupg make failure

Tags: gnupg

I got errors as below when tried to make gnupg 2.0.19

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compress.o: In function `init_uncompress':
/home/steve/Desktop/gnupg-2.0.19/g10/compress.c:147: undefined reference to `inflateInit_'

compress.o: In function `do_uncompress':
/home/steve/Desktop/gnupg-2.0.19/g10/compress.c:196: undefined reference to `inflate'

compress.o: In function `init_compress':
/home/steve/Desktop/gnupg-2.0.19/g10/compress.c:82: undefined reference to `deflateInit_'

compress.o: In function `init_uncompress':
/home/steve/Desktop/gnupg-2.0.19/g10/compress.c:147: undefined reference to `inflateInit2_'

compress.o: In function `init_compress':
/home/steve/Desktop/gnupg-2.0.19/g10/compress.c:82: undefined reference to `deflateInit2_'

compress.o: In function `compress_filter':

/home/steve/Desktop/gnupg-2.0.19/g10/compress.c:264: undefined reference to `inflateEnd'
/home/steve/Desktop/gnupg-2.0.19/g10/compress.c:273: undefined reference to `deflateEnd'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [gpg2] Error 1 
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

It looks like ld cannot find object file which owns the reference above. My question is: How to determine which file I was missing? How to resolve this issue?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Hmm, one would imagine that ./configure would have told you about missing files? Or, how did you get your Makefile generated? By the way, any particular reason you don't just install the gnupg2 package?

Comment: Hi andol, so Makefile should be where i could have a try,right. I forgot where did i got this package, but the readme file told that after Make Install there will be a gnupg2 then.

Answer (score 1):

The error messages seem to refer to the fact that you are missing the `zlib` libraries, as has been noted part of the way down the [gnupg mailing list](http://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2008-December.txt); hence the errors regarding 'inflate' and 'deflate'. So please run,

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g zlib1g-dev
```

---

**However**, you must also install the build dependencies of `gnupg2` such as `libgpg-error`, `libgcrypt`, `libksba`, and `libassuan` (>=2.0) with:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep gnupg2 
sudo apt-get install libgpg-error0 libgpg-error-dev libgcrypt11 libgcrypt11-dev
```

(You can of course download all the libraries and compile them yourself if you wish from the [gnupg site](http://www.gnupg.org/download/index.en.html) instead of using the repository versions.)

So when compiling this program there is a bit to prepare beforehand, although because you actually began the build process it would seem that the main dependencies had been satisfied for `./configure`,  even though the `zlib` libraries were missing.